# keep my phonegap application from closing while navigating to another application to copy some data

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have built an android and ios application using phonegap.
I need a user to navigate to another application on the phone and copy a token (string) and return to my app and paste it.

This works perfectly fine on android devices, but on IOS (both devices I've tested on are iphone 5 with ios7) when the user navigates away from my application and then returns, it is restarting my app.  It loads on the first page of my app & of course the context & the form they needed to paste the string into are gone.

Is there some way to keep the application from closing just for 30 seconds while a user navigates to another app and then returns?

(I've searched for information on this, but all I can find is information on creating a service.  I don't need the application to run in the background continuing to perform tasks.  It just needs to not close while a user navigates away to copy a string from another app)

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that you're somehow triggering a page reload on the iOS device when the app resumes, and the page you want to land on doesn't have a deep link.

Comment: I resolved this by disabling debugging and hydration and rebuilding my app with "Phonegap Build".  I guess hydration was forcing a restart of the app when it would lose and regain focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by disabling debugging and hydration and rebuilding my app with "Phonegap Build".  I guess hydration was forcing a restart of the app when it would lose and regain focus.